Integral of ratio of measure of balls
I'm trying to find assumptions that make the equation hold,
$$
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_\epsilon^\infty \frac{\mu(B(x,t))}{\mu(B(x,\epsilon))} dt = 0,
$$
where $x$ is in a doubling metric measure space $(X,d,\mu)$ with more than 2 points. I've applied the doubling property and found the upper bound
$$
\leq\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_\epsilon^\infty \Big( \frac{t}{\epsilon} \Big )^{\log_2(C_d)} dt
$$
where $C_d\geq 2$ is our doubling constant.
I tried splitting into sub-intervals to get
$$
\int_{2^i}^{2^{i+1}\epsilon} \Big(\frac{t}{\epsilon}\Big)^\alpha dt =\frac{2^{(i+1)(1+\alpha)}-2^{i(1+\alpha)}}{1+\alpha}\epsilon 
$$
where $\alpha = \log_2(C)$. When we sum these intervals up we get
$$
\epsilon\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{2^{(i (1 + \alpha))} (2^{(1 + \alpha)}-1) )}{(  1 + \alpha)} 
$$
where the series only converges if $2C <1$.
I also tried evaluating the integral as
$$
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_\epsilon^\infty \Big( \frac{t}{\epsilon} \Big )^{\alpha} dt = \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \frac{ \epsilon}{\alpha+1} \Big(\lim_{s \to \infty} (s/\epsilon)^{\alpha +1} - 1\Big)
$$
Normally something like an $\epsilon \to \epsilon ^\gamma$ where $\gamma > \alpha+1$ is applied but that won't work.
Are there straight forwards assumptions on the space I can assume or does this equation contradict doubling?

The limit is $\infty$, not $0$.

@geetha290krm why

Monotone Convergence Theorem.

Regardless of what properties $X, d, \mu$ have, other than $\mu$ being a measure on $X$ that is $> 0$ on balls of positive radius, the fact that $t \ge \epsilon$ means $B(x,\epsilon) \subseteq B(x,t)$ and thus $\mu(B(x,\epsilon)) \le \mu(B(x,t))$. So you are integrating an integrand $\ge 1$ over an infinite range. That will always give $\infty$ as the result, regardless of the value of $\epsilon$. $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \infty = \infty$.

And this does not contradict the doubling property, because your upper bound integral is also integrating an integrand $\ge 1$ over an infinite range, and thus is always $\infty$.
